# Deleting wrong element in array

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I have an array of a CoreData Entities. These items are then made visible in an Horizontal Scroll View. When long pressing any item the user has the option to delete that item. Well when they tap the delete button the *first* item is the only item deleted from the array.. Below is a short gif of what I mean...

[image]

Now I was advised to make everything have an ID which makes things less error prone.. so I did.. this is a snapshot of my 'CoreData' entity.

[image: Core Data Model]

and this is how I am using in code.

```
 static func removeFilter(_ filter: AirFilter, by id: String, using context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    if filter.uniqueID.uuidString == id {
        context.delete(filter)
        try? context.save()
    }
}
```

Now I am really confused because I thought I made it clear that it should **only** deleted when the id matches the id that is typed.. so now I have no idea how this code block is even firing

Comment: Doesn't each blue label has a AirFilter object connected to it? Why do you need to send both the object and the id and where do they come from? Or in other words, what is your data source that you are using for the UI?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson
`@ObservedObject var ticket: Ticket`  <-- That is the data being passed in. 
Which is then used `ForEach(ticket.filterArray) { filter in 
...  AirFilter.removeFilter(filter, by: filter.uniqueID.uuidString, using: moc)`

Comment: And yes, every blue label represents an entity

Comment: If every label has an entity object connected to it why not directly call context.delete with that object as argument?

Comment: I just tried `moc.delete(filter)
                                      
 try? moc.save()` Same effect

Comment: I think I'll try to make every label its own struct and call the delete from the child instead of the parent

Comment: The bug is probably somewhere else then

Comment: @SergioBost Try print `moc.registeredObjects.filter({ $0 is AirFilter }) as! Set<AirFilter>`. Check here that the `uniqueID`s are actually unique, and see all your objects. It may be the case that you are correctly deleting the CoreData objects, but not updating the UI correctly.

Comment: The problem was that I was only triggering a actionSheet (with a tapGesture) that would then delete the passed object. I just put the delete object inside of TapGesture itself. I won't be able to give the user the "are you sure" warning but I can live with that on this